# Почему время на insert в mysql удваивается?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Всегда использовал mysql но никогда не сталкивался с большими данными и не особо замечал данный момент. обычно размер таблицы у меня не превышал 100к строк.
но появилась необходимость добавить в таблицу 5кк строк и в mysql я заметил интересную особенность.
Примерно каждые 100к строк время на insert в таблицу mysql увеличивается вдвое.
На большие цифры по времени не смотрите записи добавлялись не напрямую в mysql а через простенькое api на node.
если первые 100к записей добавлялись за 10 - 100 мс
то после 200к время увеличились до 200 мс
после 1кк время на insert уже было 1000 мс
и так до 5000 мс что уже неприемлемо долго.
начал копать играться с настройками мускула но так и не получилось понять почему такое происходит.
Это какая то особенность mysql? Тогда я не особо понимаю как люди работают с гораздо большими данными в mysql?

Долго не мучаясь, подключил к проекту postgres для теста на стандартном конфиге и с им таких проблем у меня не было. ему особо нет разницы сколько записей в таблице бд 1 или 5кк время на insert всегда 10-30 мс.

Знатоки разъясните почему так происходит?

Структура таблицы mysql и postgres идентичны
Индексов не было.
размер буфера увеличивал в конфиге. но это не помогло время на insert заметно увеличивалось и на малых объемах данных.

```
CREATE TABLE `sitemaps` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `published_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_id` int UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by_id` int UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: у меня вопросы к вашему таймеру, потому что в запись 100 тыс строк за 0.01мс = 10мкс я просто не верю. Большинство SSD за такое время даже один fsync не сделают. `Индексов не было` - если вы не видите индекса в innodb - это не значит что его нет. В innodb вся таблица всегда является собственно primary key по своему дизайну.

Comment: @Мелкий

да сорян немного ошибся сейчас подправлю, я просто засекаю в 2 местах.
Первое это простой скрипт на питоне который обращается к rebbitmq и берет из очереди json данные и закидывает их через api в БД.
[x] Received {"url": "https://teletype.in/@monasterium/optina-30", "priority": "0.8", "last_modified": "2023-04-19T09:12:17.796+00:00Z", "username": "monasterium"}
 [x] Done / 0.01099614906311035

Второе место это терминал где вертится api на node.
[2023-06-21 11:48:13.662] http: POST /api/sitemaps (10 ms) 200